# Update Sankey chart via Socket.IO

Tags: highcharts, socket.io

I want to update my sankey chart entities as and when new ones arrive via the socket.io socket. The data sent by the socket is [sender, receiver, amount] so I have all the parameters that a sankey using Highcharts needs. I am sure of the incoming data.

I have added a function to do so, but it fails to generate anything.

```
<script>
    var render = Highcharts.chart('container', {
            title: {
                text: 'Real Time Chart'
            },

            chart: {
                type: 'sankey',
                renderTo: 'container',
                events: {
                    load: function() {
                        var socket = io.connect();
                        var series = this.series;
                        socket.on('message', function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                            series.addPoint([data.sender, data.receiver, data.amount], true, true);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },

            series: [{
                type: 'sankey',
                name: 'Initial data',
                keys: ['sender','receiver','amount'],
                data: (function() {
                    // generate some points to render before real samples arrive from feed
                    var data = []   
                    data.push({
                        sender: 'Brazil',
                        receiver: 'Portugal',
                        amount: 50
                    });
            return data;
        })()
    }]
});

    </script>
```

I am hoping to update the chart dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the `keys` property for objects. You need to use the format required by the Highcharts series:

```
series: [{
    ...,
    data: (function() {
        // generate some points to render before real samples arrive from feed
        var data = []
        data.push({
            from: 'Brazil',
            to: 'Portugal',
            weight: 50
        });
        return data;
    })()
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jrgas7Lm/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.data

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.sankey.keys

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Much appreciated. Any advice for the live update via socket.io ? I am trying to add new data to the series to animate the highchart with new data over time but cant get around to do so.

Comment: Hi @Abhishek Malik, Please try to use this code: `.addPoint({from: data.sender, to: data.receiver, weight: data.amount})`. If that does not help, please provide me with an example of your recived data (`console.log(data);` in 'message' event).